# Capturing URL from Form Submission Tracking - Google Analytics

Tags: forms, google-analytics

I'm looking to record the URL from which a form submission was sent from with Google Analytics.

---

**Example:**

Imagine domain.com. On domain.com Google Analytics (ga.js) is installed in the header.php and is on every page of the site. Similarly, in domain.com's footer.php there's the **same** contact form generated on every single page of the site.

Now, User 1 goes to domain.com. User 1 navigates to domain.com/page-c.html. User 1 submits a form from the footer contact form on page-c.html.

---

I want to know that a form was submitted from page-c.html. Or if User 2 submits from page-u.html then I know that a form was sent from page-u.html.  It is not important that I know that it is User 1 or User 2. I just want to know the URL from which the form was sent.

Anyone know how to do this with Google Analytics? -- If not, maybe another analytics service?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Google Tag Manager`. Which can not only implement all the standard analytics capabilities but also lets you add event triggers with built-in variables. For example you'd enable the `Page URL` variable in GTM and add a `Analytics Tag` of type `Event` with `Event Category, Action, Label` being things like `Contact Form, Submit, {{Page URL}}` respectively. Then create a new trigger (triggers tell when to fire a tag). This trigger should be enabled always (i.e. something like `PagePath contains /` and be of type `Form Submission`. You can target it even better by saying `trigger when` to be when the `Form ID` is equal to the `ID` attribute of your contact form. This way you prevent conflicts with other forms triggering your event tag.

You can read extensively on Google Tag Manager [here](https://www.google.ca/analytics/tag-manager/get-started/#?modal_active=none). It is a great tool to fine tune analytics and get more out of it.